# Run Built-In Function on linked server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, linked-server, functions

We have two SQL 2014 servers, and I have created a Linked Server on one of them to the other. As part of a task I'm trying to run I need to convert a SQL UserID to a username on both the local and the linked server.

On the local server I can just call

```
SELECT SUSER_NAME(1)
```

which will return the string `sa`

Is there an easy way to run the function `SUSER_NAME` on the linked server to get a value back from there?

The other alternative I think I've found is to do a join to `sys.server_principals` and pull out the name from there, but `SUSER_NAME` seems like a cleaner approach.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can execute Dynamic SQL on that Linked Server by executing `sp_executesql` on that remote server using the 4-part name. Then you just assign that to a variable marked as `OUTPUT`:

```sql
DECLARE @RemoteName sysname,
        @LoginID INT;

SET @LoginID = 267;

EXEC [LinkedServerName].master.dbo.sp_executesql
    N'SET @tmpRemoteName = SUSER_NAME(@tmpLoginID);',
    N'@tmpLoginID INT, @tmpRemoteName sysname OUTPUT',
    @tmpLoginID = @LoginID,
    @tmpRemoteName = @RemoteName OUTPUT;

SELECT @RemoteName;
```

Of course, it is debatable as to whether this is "cleaner" than JOINing to that remote table as there are pros and cons to each approach.